# VS controller 2017 error on configuration

Tags: tfs, controller

I am trying to set up the VS controller on a virtual machine, but it is giving me an error.

I have specified the lab account on the Configure Test Controller, but when I try to apply settings it is showing the error below.

Since you have not configured lab service account, make sure 
a) test agent can communicate with the test controller, 
b) test controller and test agent can access the build drop location, and 
c) Microsoft Test Manager can connect to the test controller during manual test runs. Manual steps might be needed to setup the permissions mentioned above

Both users that I am using, are local admin, on the TFS server and also on the machine that I have installed the VS controller.

[VS controller configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cgao.jpg)

Can you someone help on this?

Tks in advance.

Comment: What version of TFS is this for? The entire test controller / lab management / XAML build experience should not be used for modern versions.

Comment: The version is 2017, I need the control because I will set up the Lab management and TFS build to run UIcodedtest, the build is working already, the only problem is to set up the vs controller, I am getting the error that I posted previosly.

Tks in advance.

Comment: Lab management is **deprecated** and should not be used.